# Is there a best practice guide and annotations for a data lineage diagram

Tags: business-intelligence, diagram, data-lineage

I am looking to create a data lineage diagram showing the source and movement of some of our data across different systems and processes and found that there is not one data lineage diagram that looks the same.  I just wanted to know if there is best practice out there?  There looks like there is a lack of information out there on it too so maybe there is a more popular name it goes by?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe a UML Activity diagram would fit best?

Comment: "Data lineage" seems to be the popular name lately, so probably not a bad search term. It's rather that this field is relatively new so not much has been published so far. I'm not aware of any standard, every vendor has their own way.

Answer (score 0):

There is no real one standard for Dataflow Lineage diagrams. There are few tools in the market for presenting Lineage.
You can also find open source solutions which centralize and organize metadata and have many out-of-the-box functionalities like Lineage and Data Catalog.
Graph databases also offer solutions for creating Lineage (nodes and relationships). Enjoy!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).